# Run Python script in isolation

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I need to run a Python script from within bash in a way so it does **not** have access to any environment variables or system files/configurations. This due to an AWS boto3 client that tries to read configuration information from the environment and/or a config file.

Searching only results in how to access environment variables.

Is what I am looking for possible, and if so how?

Comment: idk docker or vm or something

Comment: @SuperStew I was hoping there was some flag to use when invoking a script.

Comment: The `chroot` command should help

Comment: @chepner not familiar with that. From what I read it only changes the execution path. How would that block access?

Comment: "does not have access to any environment variables or system files/configurations" That is rather a tall order. `bash`, even bare bones, creates some environment variables on startup.

Comment: Also: you might consider asking in [unix.se].

Comment: @SomeDutchGuy, chroot doesn't just change the path -- it restricts access to a subset of the filesystem, preventing the program from having access to files outside that subset. That's not to say that there aren't security concerns -- programs running as root, in particular, can often escape a chroot jail -- but it's a lot stronger than just a `cd`.

Comment: There are lots of other options as well -- `firejail` and similar software, f/e. I'm tempted to agree with the folks who call it a [unix.se] question more than a Stack Overflow one, though; this is content I'd expect to be common knowledge for a senior sysadmin, not as much for a developer who isn't a dedicated systems or security type.

Comment: re: preexisting questions on _this_ site, though... see [running an untrusted application on Linux in a sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437603/running-an-untrusted-application-on-linux-in-a-sandbox)

Comment: (there are also a bunch of factors that come into play wrt how your software is being run; if it's a service, for example, systemd's `DynamicUser`, `PrivateTmp`, and similar features/configuration knobs come into play, but that's _even more_ sysadmin rather than developer knowledge)

Comment: Would setting `os.environ = None` do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your command with `chroot`. For example, if you execute

```
chroot ~/newroot python yourscript.py
```

and your script tries to access `/usr/lib/some_config.txt`, it will actually try to open `~/newroot/usr/lib/some_config.txt`. As far as your script knows, `~/newroot` is the root of the local filesystem.